# Spring can't locate a driver class that *is* in the classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm trying to run a springboot app on a tomcat server that includes a datasource that's able to communicate with a vault and change db credentials during runtime.  The only change I've made in this code is adding some properties that are necessary to communicate with the vault, and changing the datasource configuration to include these vault changes.

I get the following error during startup:

Description:
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

However, in my application.properties file I DO have the driver class specified...

> spring.datasource.hikari.driverClassName=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver

and in the pom file, I have the correct dependency so the driver is infact included in the classpath...  I even see the jar in Intellij's 'External Libraries' drop down.

Again, I've not made many changes besides adding in addtional properties for our vault... and changing the code inside our datasource config to use the vault.

I've compared my changes against another module in which I did the exact same thing, and didn't have this issue at all there.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening, or suggestions on what I can try?

I've tried including a `@Import` annotation on my `@Configuration` class, which points to the vault configuration.  I've tried adding a `@ComponentScan` on my application class to try and really get it to look at the config and properties properly.

If any further detail is required please just let me know.  Thanks in advance for any and all help that can be offered.

Comment: I notice off the top of my head that your `driverClassName` does not match Boot convention of `driver-class-name`, but you should run the application in debug mode and see what the auto-configuration report says; I think you're looking for `HikariDataSourceConfiguration`.

Comment: The name of the property is `spring.datasource.driverClassName` not `spring.datasource.hikari.driverClassName`. Please add your `pom.xml` and your `application.properties` or at least the ones for `spring.datasource.*`.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem and got resolved by below annotation

```
@SpringDataApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

please provide code snippet.So, i can debug it.

Comment: Hey Sarjit, thanks for the idea. I'll give it a shot to see if it works out, unfortunately a lot of the code I'm using is internal to my organization so I won't be able to share much (to really have any effective external testing)... Mostly I'd just be able to share just a basic datasource setup, which probably wouldn't have this problem....  All that said, I'll give this idea a shot and get back to you if it worked. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Sarjit,  While this did get rid of the error, unfortunately it completely got rid of the datasource, which is necessary.  So this may not be the ideal solution to this issue.  Thanks for the advice though

Comment: could you please share data source configuration files snippet and pom.xml as well as springboot starter file